# Spring mvc multitenant view layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am seeing multitenant example for only data base layer.  I am looking for view layer to support multi tenancy.  For EX: each tenant should have their own views based on the configuration.  Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should implement your own `org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver`, and inside of that class check some configs and provide correct path for the view

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will check.